# Bitbucket pipeline sql server database set port

Tags: sql-server, django, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline that must execute django unittests. Therefore, I need a test database which should be a SQL SERVER datbase.

The pipeline looks like this:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Python.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/x4UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: python:3.7.3

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Setup sql
          image: fabiang/sqlcmd 
          script:
            - sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $DB_PASSWORD
          services:
            - sqlserver
      - step:
          name: Run tests
          caches:
            - pip
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - python3 -m venv my_env
            - source my_env/bin/activate
            - apt-get update && apt-get install
            - pip3 install -r req-dev.txt
            - python3 manage.py test
      - step:
          name: Linter
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - pip3 install flake8
            - flake8 --exclude=__init__.py migrations/
definitions:
  services:
    sqlserver: 
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
      variables: 
        ACCEPT_EULA: Y
        SA_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
```

And everytime when I run the pipeline I get:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired. 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2726.
```

I tried to do it locally but then it only work when I defined a port with the `-p` tag:
`docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong!' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`

How can I make the pipeline work? (probably defining a port but how?)

UPDATE: 
On the sqlserver tab in the result section is the following error shown:
[image]

Comment: Try adding this after `variables`: `ports: "1433:1433"`

Comment: Unfortunately, no succes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is when you call the script `- sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $DB_PASSWORD` because your sqlserver is not yet completly initialized.

Try to put a `sleep 10` before the command and the best is to add an error case if command fail `sleep 5` and retry again.